# mapMulti equivalent in rust

Tags: rust

Is there something similar to [`mapMulti`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) in rust?

I have the following contrived example:

```
fn main() {
    let buf = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let mut sum = 0;
    
    // sum even numbers and 1 in buf (1+2+4)
    buf.iter().map(|x| {
        if x % 2 == 0 {
           (true, x)
        } else {
            if *x == 1 {
                (true, x)
            } else {
                (false, x)
            }
        }
    }).for_each(|(cond, n)| {
        if cond {
            sum += n;
        }
    });
    
    println!("sum: {:?}", sum);
}
```

output:

```
sum: 7
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3398b29fb5610dc056899a063f1c2012)

I would rather write something like this instead which is more concise:

```
fn main() {
    let buf = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let mut sum = 0;

    // sum even numbers and 1 in buf (1+2+4)
    buf.iter().map_multi(|(x, consumer)| {
        if x % 2 == 0 {
           consumer.accept(x);
        } else {
            if *x == 1 {
                consumer.accept(x)
            }
        }
    }).for_each(|n| {
        sum += n
    });

    println!("sum: {:?}", sum);
}
```

Is this possible using the standard library in rust?

Comment: Return an option then call flatten

Comment: @DanielA.White I see, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0df6ff3eaaae8bbb9bb9bb48d4b1e454) ?

Comment: Like that, yes. Or you use `flat_map` or `filter_map`. Also, `sum` exists. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8654ce6dc521f39953b10c551a83973a)

Comment: yep - i forgot about `filter_map` that saves an extra call

Comment: Would it be possible to do some kind of "termination" for the iterator return value such that all following iterations return `None`? All iterations after `*x==4` should return `None` and not be in the sum: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3d53d09cd7c3244485f6eaff7a8e73f , i.e. the sum should equal 6 and not 12.

Comment: I would like to short-circuit all the following iterations, like when reading EOF.

Comment: @Kevin that’s a separate question

Comment: @DanielA.White I've added another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099075/short-circuit-iterator-once-condition-is-met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, `filter_map` does exactly what you asked for (by returning `Some(x)` instead of `(true, x)` and `None` instead of `(false, x)`. However I would write your code even more succinctly as such:

```rust
fn main() {
    let buf = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let even_or_one = buf.iter().filter(|&&n| n == 1 || n % 2 == 0);
    println!("sum: {:?}", even_or_one.sum::<i64>());
}
```