# Short-circuit iterator once condition is met

Tags: rust

I am trying to write an iterator which conditionally uses elements in a separate iterator. In my example, the separate iterator should increment the `sum` variable. Once another condition is met `*n == 4`, the iterator should stop checking the condition and assume rest of elements are increments for the `sum` variable. I have the following working example:

```
fn conditional(n: &i64) -> bool {
    // a lot of code here which is omitted for brevity
    n % 2 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let buf = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6];
    
    let mut sum = 0;
    
    let mut iter = buf.iter();
    
    while let Some(n) = iter.next() {
        if conditional(n) {
            sum += n;
        }
        if *n == 4 {
            // end of file - assume rest of elements are `conditional`
            break;
        }
    };
    
    // rest of elements [5,6]
    for n in iter {
        sum += n;
    }

    println!("sum (2+4+5+6): {:?}", sum);
}
```

output:

```
sum (2+4+5+6): 17
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce9f8e4a5116b7952c096988ec1392ab)

I would rather write the same thing with a single iterator using something like `flat_map`:

```
fn conditional(n: &i64) -> bool {
    // a lot of code here which is omitted for brevity
    n % 2 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let buf = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6];

    let mut sum = 0;
    let mut terminate = false;

    buf.iter().flat_map(|n| {
        if *n == 4 {
            // hard terminate here - return Some(n) for rest of iterator [5,6]
            terminate = true;
            return Some(n);
        }
        if terminate {
            return Some(n);
        }
        if conditional(n) {
           return Some(n);
        }
        None // odd
    })
    .for_each(|n| {
        sum += n;
    });

    println!("sum (2+4+5+6): {:?}", sum);
}
```

output:

```
sum (2+4+5+6): 17
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33e493b2e1b0cfcad0bcae47756a6da9)

Is there a way to write this in a more concise manner? I want to short-circuit the iterator once the `*n == 4` condition is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this.

Here are a couple:

```
fn conditional(n: &i64) -> bool {
    // a lot of code here which is omitted for brevity
    n % 2 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let buf = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    let sum = buf
        .iter()
        .fold((0, false), |(mut sum, mut terminate), value| {
            if *value == 4 {
                terminate = true;
            }

            if terminate || conditional(value) {
                sum += *value;
            }

            (sum, terminate)
        })
        .0;

    println!("sum (2+4+5+6): {:?}", sum);
}
```

```
sum (2+4+5+6): 17
```

Or using `filter` and a stateful closure:

```
fn conditional(n: &i64) -> bool {
    // a lot of code here which is omitted for brevity
    n % 2 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let buf = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    let sum: i64 = buf
        .iter()
        .filter({
            let mut terminate = false;
            move |&value| {
                terminate || {
                    if *value == 4 {
                        terminate = true;
                    }
                    conditional(value)
                }
            }
        })
        .sum();

    println!("sum (2+4+5+6): {:?}", sum);
}
```

```
sum (2+4+5+6): 17
```

Comment: Using `filter` might work, but given that the termination condition is expensive to compute (i.e., reading EOF), I would probably need to move the `terminate || conditional(value)` before `*value == 4`. Basically, I want to stop checking any conditions and just do `sum += n` once the termination condition is met.

Comment: Like this? (edited example #2)

Comment: yes, that is a way to short-circuit the iterator. Can I move the `terminate` variable to inside the closure?

Comment: It *is* moved inside the closure. If you try to use it after the calculation of `sum`, you get a compiler error.
However, you could move it in a little further.
Edited #2.
For clarification: the `move` keyword on the closure specifies that all external variables used get captured via move and not via reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()`:

```rust
buf.iter().filter(|n| {
    if **n == 4 {
        terminate = true;
    }
    terminate || conditional(n)
})
```

And `sum()` instead of `for_each()`:

```rust
let sum = buf
    .iter()
    .filter(|n| {
        if **n == 4 {
            terminate = true;
        }
        terminate || conditional(n)
    })
    .sum::<i64>();
```

Comment: The `sum += n` is just a placeholder for some other computation I am doing. I think the filter might work but I would rather short-circuit all succeeding iterations as in my first code snippet. Here it seems as I still need to compute `**n == 4` in each iteration even if I know that `termination` is true. I would rather have this check omitted when `termination` is true, given that the `**n == 4` might be an expensive computation (computing EOF etc.).

Comment: @Kevin You can then write `if terminate { return true; }` before or something. Really, you've pretty much reached the limit of what built in iterator adapters can do, and I know nothing on std or itertools that can help in that case (other crates may have something). You can either go with the existing or create a custom adapters.